# How to authenticate googlecl using terminal

Tags: server, command-line, authentication, google

I'm trying to use googlecl on my Ubuntu server to send pictures from my server to picasa.  I can't seem to authenticate via google using w3m, so I'm wondering if there is some other way to authenticate googlecl via OAuth.

Comment: Oh, that was easy... after w3m failed, I just hit q,y, which takes me to a googlecl prompt to visit the url with my browser.  I open that link in my local firefox (I'm connecting to the server with ssh) and authenticate it locally.  Then hit enter in the ssh terminal, which works.

Comment: Please post this as an answer by clicking the 'Answer my own question' button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here's the solution:

After w3m failed, I just hit q,y, which takes me to a googlecl prompt to visit the url with my browser. I open that link in my local firefox (I'm connecting to the server with ssh) and authenticate it locally. Then hit enter in the ssh terminal, which works.